# VB declaration of table

Tags: vb.net, declaration

I have a little problem: I want to make some app in VB and I make two CheckedListBoxs and I have some idea: if I chose something in CheckedListBox1 I want to show some date inside CheckedListBox2.

I have a problem with declaration - I make something like this:

```
Dim model3 = {"A", "B", "C"}
```

But I have only one information inside CheckedListBox2: 'String[]'

```
If CheckedListBox1.CheckedItems.Count <> 0 Then

    If CheckedListBox1.SelectedItem.ToString = "GWW" Then
        Marka.Items.Add(model1)

    ElseIf CheckedListBox1.SelectedItem.ToString = "AWW" Then
        Marka.Items.Add(model2)
    ElseIf CheckedListBox1.SelectedItem.ToString = "ZWW" Then
        Marka.Items.Add(model3)
    End If
Else
    Marka.Items.Clear()
End If
```

Could you give me some prompt? I do not have too much experience so if I could asked as simple as possible :)

Answer (score 1):

That's because you're only adding one item - the array itself - and the `CheckedListBox` will call its `ToString` method to get text that it can display, which is what you see.  If what you actually want to do is add all the elements in the array into the `CheckedListBox` then you need to call `AddRange` rather than `Add`.

Comment: Thank You it's work. And what if I want make add/remove from CheckListBox2? Right now I only clear whole list (sometimes and sometimes not).

Comment: The issue you had has been resolved. Accept the answer and be done with this thread.  If you have a new question, post it as a new question with all the information relevant to the new question and none that is specific to this old question.

Comment: OK I'm new one next time I will do it like You said.